# Find lowest score in hierarchy made of strings

Tags: javascript

Say you have an array of subchallenges like this :

```
subchallenges = [
    {name: 'score',
     result: 'gold'},
    {name: 'time',
     result: 'bronze'},
    ...and so on.... ]
```

And you need to find the final score, which is just equal to the lowest result in any the subchallenges. The ranking hierarchy goes

```
['gold', 'silver', 'bronze', 'none']
```

so in the example array above, if it only consisted of those subchallenge-objects, the final score would equal bronze. What would you consider the best way to do this?

Comment: this is not suitable for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should put some integer values to your string ratings:

```
var ratings = {
    'gold' : 3,
    'silver' : 2,
    'bronze' : 1,
    'none' : 0
}
```

then looping through the challenges is easy:

```
function getRating(subchallenges)
{
    var result = 'gold';
    var lowestRate = 3;
    var numRates = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<subchallenges.length;i++)
    {
        var rate = ratings[subchallenges[i].result];
        if(rate > 0 && rate < lowestRate)
        {
            lowestRate = rate;
            result = subchallenges[i].result;
            numRates++;
        }
    }
    if(numRates == 0) return 'none';
    return result;
}
```

Edit: fixed it so it will return 'none' instead of 'gold' when all challenges are 'none'

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the array:

```
var lowest = "gold";
for (var i = 0; i < subchallenges.length; i++){
    ...
}
```

Keep track of the current lowest score using `lowest` and if it is lower then update it.